# How to Write Data weave Transformation for a database Result map

Tags: mule, dataweave

Hi My Data base result is like below

[image]

```
**First Row Result**
TABLE_NAME  = LOAN
PATH_NAME = /loan
COLUMN_NAME = AMOUNT
ATTRIBUTE_NAME = loanAmount
**Second Row Result** 
TABLE_NAME  = BORROWER
PATH_NAME = /borrower
COLUMN_NAME = AMOUNT
ATTRIBUTE_NAME = baseAmount
```

My Expected JSON Output is below , i does not want to hardcode anything inside config , everything is available inside DB Result set.

```
config :{
    loanAmount : { // ATTRIBUTE_NAME  from first Object in DB Result
        TABLE_NAME : LOAN, // Key name from DB Result : Value for that key.
        PATH_NAME : /loan,
        COLUMN_NAME : AMOUNT,
        ATTRIBUTE_NAME : loanAmount
    },
    baseAmount : {
        TABLE_NAME : BORROWER,
        PATH_NAME : /borrower,
        COLUMN_NAME : AMOUNT,
        ATTRIBUTE_NAME : baseAmount
    }
 }
```

Tried with some map iteration but not getting the exact way i am looking for.

Comment: Is that DB result exactly the way it is shown ( if so what's the mime/content type?) , or is it a List of Objects that you get which is then worked upon and generates the output that you expect?

Comment: Added a Screen shot of DB Result set . Media Type is application/java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
output application/json
var input1 = [{"TABLE_NAME":"LOAN", "PATH_NAME":"/loan", "COLUMN_NAME": "AMOUNT", "ATTRIBUTE_NAME": "loanAmount"},{"TABLE_NAME":"BORROWER", "PATH_NAME":"/borrower", "COLUMN_NAME": "AMOUNT", "ATTRIBUTE_NAME": "baseAmount"}]
---
config: input1 map {
        ($.ATTRIBUTE_NAME):
           ($)
       
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "config": [
    {
      "loanAmount": {
        "TABLE_NAME": "LOAN",
        "PATH_NAME": "/loan",
        "COLUMN_NAME": "AMOUNT",
        "ATTRIBUTE_NAME": "loanAmount"
      }
    },
    {
      "baseAmount": {
        "TABLE_NAME": "BORROWER",
        "PATH_NAME": "/borrower",
        "COLUMN_NAME": "AMOUNT",
        "ATTRIBUTE_NAME": "baseAmount"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```